# How to pub/sub an external MongoDB in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to make a pub/sub from my external MongoDB to my client (React + Redux).

The main mongo runs on port 3001 (default database of Meteor) and the remote mongo runs on port 27017.

When I publish records from the 3001-mongo, and subscribe to it from client, everything just fine. However, when I do the same thing but with 27017-mongo, the client also could receive the records but when that records change (using robo3T), the client cannot reactive.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use both mongoDBs at the same time. How are you setting up the external one? using `MONGO_URL`? if yes then it should just work.

Comment: Im using: 
 `new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(Meteor.settings.REMOTE_MONGO_URL)`

Comment: oh, well that, as it says, is internal mongo stuff. I would not expect this to work. Do you really need two different DBs?

Comment: yes, the 3001-mongo using for log in/out in my web and the 270170-mongo contains data of another website.